# Next js Custom Directory with Vercel

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

i want to ask about how to deploy next js with vercel.

Here I have the next js structure which I have changed.

- frontend (Next js Current Directory)
- node_modules
- next.config.js
- jsconfig.json
- package-lock.json
- package.json

Script in package.json.

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next frontend dev",
    "build": "next build frontend",
    "start": "next start frontend",
    "lint": "next lint frontend"
},
```

Script in next.config.js.

```js
const path = require('path')

const alias = {
  '@/components': path.join(__dirname, 'frontend', 'components'),
  '@/containers': path.join(__dirname, 'frontend', 'containers'),
  '@/styles': path.join(__dirname, 'frontend', 'scss')
}

module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/scss')]
  },
  images: {
    domains: ['source.unsplash.com'],
    loader: 'imgix', // this is a hack until the bug is fixed
    path: 'https://noop/'
  },
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias = Object.assign(
      {},
      config.resolve.alias,
      alias
    )

    return config
  }
}
```

When I import to vercel and deploy only the builds are successful, Then follow with this message:

> Error: The file "/vercel/path1/.next/routes-manifest.json" couldn't be found. This is normally caused by a misconfiguration in your project.

Do I have to adjust the build output? or is there a better way.

Comment: Where is your `pages` folder located?

Comment: @juliomalves in `frontend`  directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with override **OUTPUT DIRECTORY** in vercel use `frontend/.next`.
Hope this helps others.